# Can't subscribe topic within a rqt_plugin

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros

I have a GUI as a rqt plugin and I want to subscribe a topic but I can't see my  rqt_plugin node on the rqt_graph.
The topic which i want to subscribe is in the same machine, which I want to start my rqt_plugin. I have muliple machines and I start the rqt_graph at the another machine. At the another machine I see all the other topics and I see also the topic which I want to subscribe with my rqt_plugin.

Here is the creation of the publisher at machine A:

```
 pubCmd = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/sci/cmd", 10);
```

Here is the subscribing of the topic /sci/cmd at my rqt_plugin also at machine A:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = getNodeHandle().subscribe("/sci/cmd", 10, &ccgui::receiveSC, this);
```

If now I published something, my rqt plugin receives nothing. I know that the publisher works correctly  because I subscribed the topic with a normal node and I receive the messages.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Why don't you post this in http://answers.ros.org ?

Comment: http://answers.ros.org/question/199858/rqt_myplugin-cant-subscribe-node/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the problem.

I created a local subscriber, which always was deleted if the program leaved the method.
So simple but so fatal.

Now I create a object variable and it works.